# What factors affect drift current in a PN junction?

Tags: semiconductor-physics

My textbook just says that in a unbiased PN junction the diffusion current and drift current are equal. In forward biased junction the diffusion current is higher than drift current and in  reverse biased junction the drift current is higher than diffusion current.

I understand the above concepts but in reality what factors affect drift current in depletion layer in a PN junction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the basic model, the drift current is proportional to the number of charge carriers, electron-hole pairs thermally generated within the depletion layer. The strong electrical field will swipe the electrons one way and the holes in the other direction, both contributing to the current. Basically all carriers that are there, so that the drift current does not depend on field strength.

So in this picture, the drift current depends exponentially on reciprocal temperature:
$$
I_d \propto e^\frac{-E_g}{2kT}.
$$

But things are a bit more complicated, see for example these [notes by Fernsler](https://web.calpoly.edu/~jfernsle/Classes/PHYS452/Labs/452LMExp15W13.pdf).