# Where does the drift current in a pn juntion come from?

Tags: electricity, electric-fields, semiconductor-physics

I know I know. There are around 4 similar questions on here, but they do not properly answer my question.

I'd like to know where the drift current in a pn juntion (no bias) comes from. From what Youtube videos and animations tell me, it is supposed to be the randomly by thermal energy created hole /electron pairs that are being propelled by the electric field in the depletion zone. That doesn't make sense to me, because I would think that the the minority charges would be repelled by the ions in their respective half of the junction. To me it seems like they need to overcome a force first to get into the depletion region where they then would be accelerated to the other side.
The answer to [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/512797/what-factors-affect-drift-current-in-a-pn-junction) question was the first time I saw anyone mention that its only the pairs formed in the depletion region. The given link is dead. Can anyone give me more information about that?

Comment: I'll be leaving some points here for a heuristic explanation. 1) Net Drift Current can't be there without a bias. 2) Both semiconductors are neutral and only charged zone is depletion region. 3) There is always a movement of electrons in a material due to random fluctuations in body which results in generation and annihilation of "charge". 4) Now, there are situation when electrons can gain enough momentum to cross the local fields near depletion region. (They can tunnel through the barrier too, if you are being precise. Though semiclassical picture would work too "most of the times").

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The sources I found so far say, that there is a diffusion current ( what i think you describe in 4) ). Where the majority charges (holes technically aren't charge, just missing electrons) cross to the other side despite the E-field. And then they describe a drift current of the minority charges, which cancels out the other one and will lead to an equilibrium (what I describe in the question). This current is supposed to rise with higher voltage at the depletion region. I wonder how that works

Comment: Have you seen and understood a pn junction band diagram? There is no energy barrier they have to overcome. It is in fact the opposite, an energy slope that electrons ride down to lower energy. That is the electric field. The answer will be easiest to explain with band diagrams.

Comment: I just looked at it. (and watched some videos on it) I wasn't planning on understanding the pn junction at a very deep level. I guess my confusion comes from the fact that I thought as the outer regions of the p-type material are net neutral and the part in the depletion region is negative, electrons would have a hard time going to the depletion zone. Maybe I imagine it the wrong way.

Comment: @Matt Yes, I understand that looking at the bands, you dont see much. But again bands are based upon very crude model and includes a lot many approximations which wont give you these microscopical interactions. My answer is solely based on the pictorial model we see most of the times in semiconductor theory not on band structure. Band structure are constantly been modified to include these effects though (an example is Tunnel diode).

Comment: @Prabhat What are you talking about? Yes, band diagrams are an approximation, most models are. But they are a very good approximation. No modification is needed to explain tunnel diodes, their behavior is easily explained with a normal band diagram.